# What is a good way to test for inheritance of Backbone-extended constructors?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I test if a constructor extends another constructor, Backbone.js-style, where inheritance is set up via Backbone's `extend` method? And don't say `instanceof` :). I'm not talking about objects. I'm talking about constructors.

E.g.: Take a constructor like the one produced by the following code:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend();
```

Now, in another spot in the code, how can you test that somewhere in its prototype chain, `var my_router = new MyRouter` has the properties of `Backbone.Router.prototype`?

Comment: my only comment is: why? why do you need this?

Comment: @alexanderb: i wanted this for testing. concretely, in my case, i have `inherits` bound to `PR.test.utils.inherits`, and:
`ok(PR.test.utils.inherits(PR.Router, Backbone.Router), 'The function at PR.Router Backbone-extends Backbone.Router.');`

Comment: is it stupid/too much?

Comment: Basically, "knowing the type" is violation of good design.. So ya, I would call it bit silly.

Comment: @alexanderb: i'm doing this only in tests, where i am seeking to elucidate the spec. In application code it's all ducked: there is no type knowing. Is this bad in tests too, you think? There i am specing

Comment: @mu i want to know whether objects created by `MyRouter` will have a prototype chain that includes `Backbone.Event`'s `.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
var inherits = function(child, parent) {
  if (!_.isFunction(child) || !_.isFunction(parent)) 
    throw new Error('`child` and `parent` must be functions.'); 

  return _.reduce(Object.getPrototypeOf(child.prototype), function(memo,  child_prototype__proto__) {    
    return _.contains(parent.prototype, child_prototype__proto__) && memo;
  }, true);
}
```

So, you can do:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend();
inherits(MyRouter, Backbone.Router) // true
inherits(MyRouter, Backbone.Model) // false
```

This works for single-layer Backbone-style inheritance, wherein Backbone's `extend` function was used as above.

The works because because Backbone's `extend` does the following when it sets up the prototype chain, where `child` is the constructor you get at the end and `parent` is the constructor you're extending:

```
var Surrogate = function(){ this.constructor = child; };
Surrogate.prototype = parent.prototype;
child.prototype = new Surrogate;
```

So, a constructor that results from `extend` has all of its parent's prototype properties on its `.prototype.__proto__` property. If this is new or confusing, you can read more about this on [John Resig's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/). Essentially, `"test".__proto__ === String.prototype`.

Comment: Backbone sets an internal `__super__` property that might be of use: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uTGrf/ . `__super__` is undocumented though.